# the term “constant” in Elisp

Tags: elisp

The definition of the term “***constant***” is clarified in the [*GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual*, section 6.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Arrays.html):

> For purposes of evaluation, the array is a constant—i.e., it evaluates to itself.

In the *manual*, “***constant***” means that one object always evaluates to itself; it is so different from most other languages.

I also noticed that Elisp uses the term “***literal***” as well (e.g., [2.9 Mutability](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mutability.html)).

---

How is the term “***constant***” different from “***literal***”?

Is “evaluate to self” exactly the only definition of the term “***constant***”?

Comment: Until I read Chapter 6, I thought it used the definition in the C language.

Comment: The question encourages opinion-based answer, and so it should be closed. Whether something is "good" or not is a discussion topic. Please take it to a discussion site, such as Reddit.

Comment: You can use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report a doc bug or a doc enhancement request. That's what I suggest for your quest here.

Comment: @Drew: I will edit and improve my question tomorrow. Thanks for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Does it have only one definition just mentioned in that section?

You also won't like the other usage of "constant".

`defconst` can be used to define an intended-to-be-constant variable, but no "constant"-ness of that variable is enforced -- it can be set to another value just like any variable.  The only actual difference between `defconst` and `defvar` is that when loading or re-loading a library, the `defvar`s will not reset pre-existing values, whereas any `defconst`s will set the value unconditionally.

This makes more sense than you might first think, when you consider that elisp libraries may be updated to newer versions within the lifespan of a running Emacs instance, and the new version of a library may have cause to change such a "constant", which is very different to a C program being recompiled after changing its code, or modifying and re-running some short-lived program (bearing in mind that Emacs sessions can last for *months*).

Comment: So, ***constant*** means that the ***binding* will not change**, instead of the value?  Because I can change an array's value, [see my comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76028/the-term-constant-in-gnu-emacs-lisp-reference-manual/76029?noredirect=1#comment124521_76029)

Comment: I'm not even sure what you mean by that, but "constant" in the `defconst` sense isn't much more than a statement of intent -- an otherwise-normal variable which is not *intended* to be changed, but which absolutely *can* be changed if the user chooses to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Some other languages have adopted the term “literal” (such as a “string literal” or an “object literal”), but that doesn’t mean that Emacs Lisp should change the terminology it uses. After all, Emacs Lisp has been around a lot longer.

Comment: At the very least, **it should have clarified the definition of the term earlier** than it did until Section 6.2, IMHO.

Comment: The first usage in chapter 1.3.2 does clarify the meaning. Anyway, if you want to suggest a change you need to send a patch to the emacs-devel mailing list. Complaining about it here on StackExchange will accomplish nothing.

Comment: Do you mean “This is so that you do not need to quote them to use them as constants in a program.” in 1.3.2?  I am sorry, to me (an Elisp beginner), it is not clarified enough.  Also, I heard that a ***literal*** string in the C language should not be changed, but a ***constant*** in Elisp can be changed (6.2 says an array has the characteristic that it is a constant, and I know that an array can be `aset`).

Comment: A string literal in a C program _can_ be changed, if you want to. But you’re right, you shouldn’t change it. Likewise, a constant in a Lisp program is a value that was included as part of the source code; changing it would change that source. This comes up often when considering the difference between a function like `reverse` and one like `nreverse`. The latter modifies its argument, while the former copies it. If you use `nreverse` on a list that was part of the source code (a constant), your program probably will not operate as you intend.